# Search in a table of three columns where search criteria may be just one column or two column or three column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have a database table contains email, code, name. I have a view search page which can take just email as input or just code or just name or email and name or email and code or email, name, code or nothing. So whichever the search criteria is I need to return related rows from the database. How can I manage my query? Any suggestion? Is there any best practice?

Note: Actually I have three tables and from there I get those data by join query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The typical method is:

```
where (? is null or email = ?) and
      (? is null or code = ?) and
      (? is null or name = ?)
```

This requires passing each parameter twice.  So, this is a good reason to use named parameters:

```
where (:email is null or email = :email) and
      (:code is null or code = :code) and
      (:name is null or name = :name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to be a little bit more clear. Suppose I search with the 'forhad@mail.com'. Then the query will be like( please make me clear at this point) - 
where ('forhad@mail.com' is null or email = 'forhad@mail.com') and
      (? is null or code = ?) and
      (? is null or name = ?)

?

Thanks

Comment: @forhadmethun . . . Basically, except presumably the `?` would be filled in with `NULL` because those parameters do not have values.